# About send a picture on posting an event

Tags: php, facebook, events

I would like to upload a picture to Facebook event.

I don't understand the means of "@" in [this answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9718301/posting-picture-on-event-page). Can't I specify picture URL on the Internet directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you cant upload a image from the root folder or the specified folder of server where you have your code. You cant link a picture path to this code.

"@" -> which is facebook standard to point the realpath of a picture you gonna upload.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I save an external server's picture to my server first, and transmit it. I still wonder that a picture uploads automatically only by attaching the sign.

Comment: @Tank2005 See, because we just providing them path and filename. Once we use the API its just pickup the image from path that we provided and post's it in wall.